# How to exclude results based on sql condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am creating a job application portal using Codeigniter and MySQL. I have the following tables:

- jobs - which contains the list of jobs
- students - which contains the list of students
- jobs_applied - which contains the applied jobs list by students

### **jobs**

primary key: `job_id`.

**columns: `job_id`, `job_name`**

### **students**

primary key: `student_id`.

**columns: `student_id`, `student_name`, `student_email`**

### **jobs_applied**

primary key: `jobs_applied_id`.

foreign key: `job_id`, `student_id`.

**columns: `job_id`, `student_id`, `status`, `applied_date`**

In my app, when a user applies for a job then i change the status columns in `jobs_applied` to "pending". I want to remove the applied jobs from the list.

So far, i am using the following query to list the jobs.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
```

I have tried using `INNER JOIN` against the `jobs_applied`, but i am stuck in it. I don't know how to exclude it from the list. I have the `student_id` in my session.

**How to create a query that excludes the jobs applied by the students using `student_id` as a condition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do the LEFT JOIN to jobs_applied with reference to a specific student, and where there is no match, jobs_applied.* will be NULL, so that's your WHERE condition.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    ->   `job_id` int NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
    -> );

mysql> INSERT INTO `jobs` VALUES (11),(22);

mysql> CREATE TABLE `students` (
    ->   `student_id` int NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
    -> );

mysql> INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (100),(200);

mysql> CREATE TABLE `jobs_applied` (
    ->   `jobs_applied_id` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `job_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `student_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `status` int DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`jobs_applied_id`),
    ->   KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
    ->   KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `jobs_applied_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`job_id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `jobs_applied_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`student_id`)
    -> );

mysql> INSERT INTO `jobs_applied` VALUES (1,11,100,NULL),(2,22,200,NULL);
```

Student 100 applied for job 11 and he should therefore see only job 22 in the subsequent query.

```
mysql> SELECT j.*
    -> FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN jobs_applied ap
    ->  ON j.job_id = ap.job_id AND ap.student_id = 100
    -> WHERE ap.job_id IS NULL;
+--------+
| job_id |
+--------+
|     22 |
+--------+
```

Likewise, student 200 applied for job 22 so she should only see job 11 afterwards.

```
mysql> SELECT j.*
    -> FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN jobs_applied ap
    ->  ON j.job_id = ap.job_id AND ap.student_id = 200
    -> WHERE ap.job_id IS NULL;
+--------+
| job_id |
+--------+
|     11 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select all job which are not found in applied table (with your desired student). easiest way imho is with subselect, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs as j
WHERE j.job_id NOT IN (
 SELECT job_id FROM jobs_applied WHERE student_id IN (<student_id>)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - use left join and where condition

```
  SELECT a.job_id
  FROM jobs a LEFT JOIN jobs_applied b ON a.job_id=b.job_id
  WHERE status IS null
```

Comment: I want to display list of jobs except the jobs which the user is already applied. in your query there's no `student_id`

Comment: could u please add some sample data and your expected output in table format - it'll be then much easy to understand what do u want @BearNithi

Comment: How to create a query that excludes the jobs applied by the students using `student_id` as a condition? I am sorry i dont know how to create table view in question

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, to keep a list of jobs that a student have not applied for, use

```
select * from jobs j LEFT JOIN jobs_applied ap on j.job_id=ap.jobs_id where ap.jobs_id is null
```

Comment: I want to display list of jobs except the jobs which the student has already applied. in your query there's no `student_id`.

Comment: Do you have student_id in jobs? Could you list all the columns that you have in your tables jobs,  students, and jobs_applied?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM jobs Where Job_Id not in (Select job_id from jobs_applied where ISNULL(status,'') ='')
```

Comment: I want to display list of jobs except the jobs which the student has already applied. in your query there's no `student_id`.